# ld: framework not found System

Tags: c++, macos, ld, maya

I am compiling the plug-in samples for Autodesk Maya 2014 with the Makefile it ships with. The thing is, 'ld' fails to locate a framework called 'System', thus giving the message:

```
  ld: framework not found System
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So where could that framework be located? The version of my Mac OS X is 10.8.3. Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks a lot.

Comment: When asking a question about an error from a command-line utility, it’s useful to post the full offending command-line invocation. Otherwise, it’s hard to tell what’s going on. For what it’s worth, system frameworks are located at /System/Library/Frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue setting Xcode Build Setting, on Target, to SDKROOT [image: Xcode working configuration]